# Disable Dock Shadow in Mavericks

Tags: macos, dock

[image]

Am I the only one, or is there anyone else who finds that shadow ontop of a nearby window annoying?

Comment: Did this work 100% for you? The answer you selected doesn't work at all in Yosemite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must run this:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock hide-mirror -bool true; killall Dock
```

This enables a more transparent dock but also removes the annoying shadow.

**Note: this fix is specifically for OS X Mavericks**

Comment: awesome! http://ablage.stabentheiner.de/2013-11-27_Bildschirmfoto_2013-11-27_um_14.35.50.png

Comment: @SimonD.Seim the link above is broken.

Comment: Was just a screenshot how it looks

Comment: Doesn't work - still a shadow (in Yosemite)

Comment: I have asked the same question about Yosemite: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151977/remove-3d-shadow-on-vertical-dock-in-yosemite/151985#151985

Answer (score 1):

## Try …

In Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock showshadow -bool NO
```

– then quit Dock.

### Reference

Blacktree Secrets [secret 2342](http://secrets.blacktree.com/edit?id=2342).

### Hint

The preference pane for [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com) can write the preference and perform the quit.

### If the preference does not work as expected, for your Dock to the left

Please be aware of the following bug report in Open Radar –

[OS X Mavericks: Left/right Dock should not cast a shadow on windows](http://openradar.appspot.com/14706148)

– but note that the report was for unreleased build 13A538g of the OS (not for 13A603).

Comment: doesn't work - the shadow remains

Answer (score 0):

Disable totally:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool true
```

EDIT: This is only for screenshot function.

Haven't tried it, but this
[app](https://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/)
 should have an option for disable totally.

Comment: This switch disables the shadow of windows when you're taking screenshots

Comment: Ahh yeah I see now. I didnt try the cmd last night. Did you try the app Nocturne? It should contain a option for totally disable it, still havent tried that, just I friend that told me he used it a year ago for that.

Comment: Nocturne completely disables shadows (also shadows of windows) https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbnhlcw83dkrxyl/Screenshot%202013-11-10%2017.18.28.png - It works like this if you just want to have a tool for shadows https://github.com/puffnfresh/toggle-osx-shadows