# Remove 3D shadow on vertical Dock in Yosemite

Tags: dock, macos

I have an 11" Macbook Air + Yosemite with vertical dock.

The dock causes a large irritating shadow over any windows...
[image]

I have tried these (found on various sites - reference Mavericks):

```
defaults write com.apple.dock hide-mirror -bool true; killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock showshadow -bool NO; killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -boolean YES; killall Dock
```

The shadow remains after running all of these.

Is it possible to remove the shadow? (I do not want to disable any other effect - only the dock shadow).

Thanks

Comment: I want to do the same but also didn't find anything yet. Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: No but the shadow seems less heavy in El Capitan

Comment: for me it is still too much. I hope there will be a way to change it in the future. Till then all my windows need a "safe distance" to the dock ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying out [cDock](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/51149/cdock), and so far it seems to do the job.

Comment: Thanks - it's not clear how I would remove the shadow only? I'm happy otherwise with how it looks.

Comment: I want to do the same like the creator of this question and I downloaded cDock. First it doesn't want to do its thing unless you deactivate Apple's new "rootless" feature which prevents system changes. But apart from that, I didn't find anything in the app that would let me change that shadow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html)? It covers many such tweaks (although I have not checked for this one).

Comment: Thanks I downloaded it - can't see any dock shadow settings